# Continuous Banach valued function $u:[0,\infty] \rightarrow V$ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $V$ be a Banach space and $u:[0,\infty] \rightarrow V$ be continuous. Then for every sequence of partitions $\Delta_{n}:0=t^{(n)}_{0}\leq...\leq t^{(n)}_{n}=1$ s.t. $\|\Delta_{n}\| \rightarrow 0$ the limit

$
\int_{0}^{1}u(r)dr := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}u(t^{(n)}_{k})(t^{(n)}_{k}-t^{(n)}_{k-1}))
$

exists and doesn't depend on the choice of the sequence of partitions.

I am learning something about the generator of a $C0$-semigroup and at some point this integral is introduced. But I can't figure out why this is true. I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Of course you only need $u$ continuous on $[0,1]$.  This is an instructive problem.  Good for testing the student's understanding of the concepts.  *Hints:* To show the limit exists, you show it is a Cauchy sequence.  Note $u$ is *uniformly continuous*.  To show independence of the choice, given any two such sequences "intertwine" them into another such sequence, where each of the originals is a subsequence.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried to show that this is a Cauchy sequence but I wasn't able to use the uniform continuity there. Do you have a hint for that?